# Bash regex using bash_rematch not capturing as expected

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to capture `BAR_BAR` in `FOO_FOO_FOO_BAR_BAR` using the following regex: `(?:.*?_){3}(.*)`.

The regular expression works when using a validator such as RegExr or regex101, but Bash doesn't return anything when I run:

```
text="FOO_FOO_FOO_BAR_BAR"
regex="(?:.*?_){3}(.*)"

[[ $text =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

When I run the following example regex it works perfectly (returning `b`):

```
text="abcdef"
regex="(b)(.)(d)e"
[[ $text =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

I'm new to using regex in Bash, what am I missing here?

Comment: POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups and lazy quantifiers.

Comment: bash uses "extended regular expressions", as in `grep -E`,  not PCRE or javascript or other "advanced" flavours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups and lazy quantifiers. Bash uses POSIX ERE, so you can use

```sh
text="FOO_FOO_FOO_BAR_BAR"
regex="([^_]*_){3}(.*)"
[[ $text =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
# => BAR_BAR
```

Here,

- `([^_]*_){3}` - matches three occurrences (Group 1) of any zero or more chars other than `_` followed with a `_` char
- `(.*)` - the rest of the string (Group 2).

As in this case a capturing group is used to serve a grouping construct at the beginning, `"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` holds the required value.

Comment: Pedantically, only the first of the 3 occurrences (`FOO_`) is captured in group 1.

Comment: @glennjackman Actually, it is the last of these 3 occurrences.

Comment: So it is. That's surprising behaviour for me.

Comment: Ha, that explains! In this case, let's say text is `FOO_FOO_FOO_BAR_BAR_XYZ` and I want to get only `BAR_BAR`, how do I exclude `_XYZ_ from matching?

Comment: @32bitsago Then use `regex="([^_]*_){3}([^_]+_[^_]+)"` or `regex="([^_]*_){3}([^_]*_[^_]*)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually meant the literally string "_XYZ" :)

Comment: @32bitsago If the string is always there after your expected match, use `regex="([^_]*_){3}(.*)_XYZ"`